# Insert html tags to mixed string with php

Tags: javascript, php, html, regex, dom

I have a string containing mixed text and html mark up (e.g. anchors, underlines) such as:

```
$string = 'text1<a href="">text2</a> text3';
```

I'd like to wrap text1, text2 and text3 with span tags.

This needs to be done precisely so that the original html tags don't brake. I.e. the final result should be:

```
$new_string = '<span>text1</span><a href=""><span>text2</span></a><span>text3</span>';
```

Any ideas how to do that?

Comment: `$new_string = '<span>text1</span><a href=""><span>text2</span></a><span>'.$string.'</span>';`

Comment: Do you want to add tags dynamically ? with JavaScript ?

Comment: And what about strings like `'<div data-text1="text2">text3</div>'`?

Comment: No, doesn't need to be dynamic. It's a string from a database, all string manipulation is done with PHP.

Comment: I am looking for a solution that can isolate the text from any mark up, perhaps using "<" and ">" as delimiters and wrap <span> around each isolated text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found the one line solution:

JS:

```
function addSpans($string){
  str.replace(/[^<>]+(?=<[^<>]+>)|[^<>]+$/g, (text) => {return "<span>"+text+"</span>";})
}
```

PHP:

```
function addSpans($input){
  return preg_replace("/[^<>]+(?=<[^<>]+>)|[^<>]+$/","<span>$0</span>",$input);
}
```

How it works:
`[^<>]+(?=<[^<>]+>)|[^<>]+$` matches any string that matches `[^<>]+(?=<[^<>]+>)` or that matches `[^<>]+$`

`[^<>]+(?=<[^<>]+>)`: Any string followed by an html tag

`[^<>]+` matches one or more characters that are not < or >

`(?=<[^<>]+>)` matches a < followed by one or more characters that are not < or > followed by a >. This matches any html tag

`[^<>]+$`: Any string with out html tag at the end of the input

`[^<>]+$` same as `[^<>]+` but at the end of the input

To add the span tags in JS you have to pass a function, that takes the matched string as input, as replacement.

In PHP you can reference the matched string in the replacment using $0-99 where $0 is the string that matched the entire pattern.

---

Couldn't find a way to do it with a single line using regex but this function should work.

JS code:

```
function addSpans($string){
  text = $string.split(/<[^>]+>/g);
  tags = $string.match(/<[^>]+>/g);
  retvar = "";
  for(i = 0; i < text.length;i++){
    if(typeof text[i] !== 'undefined' && text[i].length > 0){
      retvar += "<span>"+text[i]+"</span>";
    }
    if(typeof tags[i] !== 'undefined'){
      retvar += tags[i];
    }    
  }
  return retvar;
}
```

---

PHP code:

```
function addSpans($input){

  $text = preg_split('/<[^>]+>/',$input);
  $tags = array();
  preg_match_all('/<[^>]+>/',$input,$tags);
  $retvar = "";
  for($i = 0; $i < count($text);$i++){      
    if(isset($text[$i]) && strlen($text[$i]) > 0){
      $retvar .= "<span>".$text[$i]."</span>";
    }
    if(isset($tags[0][$i])){
      $retvar .= $tags[0][$i];
    }    
  }
  return $retvar;
}
```

---

The code works like this:

1.: Split string by HTML tags

how the regex works:

`<` matches the character < (opening html tag)

`[^>]+` matches one or more characters that´s not a > (closing html tag)

`>` matches the character > (closing html tag)

2.: Get the HTML tags. Same regex but now used for matching instead of spliting

3.: In a loop:

3.1: surround the current text with span tags if current text is not empty (as is if the input begins/ends with a tag)

3.2: add the HTML tag that was used for spliting again.

3.3: reapeat with next text and next html tag.

4.: eventually return composed string.

I also check if the current text/tag exists in both codes in case they are not of equal length.

Comment: With your example it gives the output you wanted when I test it. In which case doesn´t it work for you?

Comment: Did you mean to write that in php or js? Seems like a mix.

Comment: Sorry I dont know how to implement it. When i pasted it in my php script, there were a lot of errors

Comment: That is javascript code. Maybe i can find a way to do in php too.

Comment: You are right. It does work in js. Thanks you very much for your help! That is excellent. Would you mind explaining a little bit more how the code works and in particular the regular expressions?

Comment: Please do let us know if you come up with a PHP alternative